# Solving "the lexer hack"/"typedef-name: identifier" problem in BNFC

Tags: parsing, lexer, bnfc

I'm trying to parse CPP using BNFC and I've come to the "typedef-name: identifier" problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack).

This is the spec for BNFC: https://bnfc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

The problem comes up when a new type is defined in a program (In C using `typedef`) and needs to be lexed as a type for the parser to handle it correctly, but lexing stage has already occured. Other systems have hacks around this issue but I'm not sure how to solve it in BNFC.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I am also having many issues with using BNFC, which seems not stable at all.

Comment: The google group can be a useful resource (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bnfc-dev)